# Minecraft tick.json not behaving properly

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

This is what is written in the datapack function:

```
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=0}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -125 2.5
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=1}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -112 3 
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=2}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -125 11
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=3}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -112 12.5
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=5}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -68 3
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=6}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -55 2.5
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=7}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -68 12.5
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=8}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -55 11
```

Tick.json is performing the function every tick but instead of making the player look at the specified spots when a certain slot is in use, the player gets teleported to weird coordinates. Well now you might think that there is something wrong with the command, but long and behold the function works perfectly if I run it manually. The tick function is one I copied over from a 1.14.4 datapack, but the rest is a 1.15 datapack. Anyone got any clue on what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=0}] run tp @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=0}] ~ ~ ~ -125 2.5
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=1}] run tp @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=1}] ~ ~ ~ -112 3 
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=2}] run tp @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=2}] ~ ~ ~ -125 11
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=3}] run tp @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=3}] ~ ~ ~ -112 12.5
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=5}] run tp @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=5}] ~ ~ ~ -68 3
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=6}] run tp @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=6}] ~ ~ ~ -55 2.5
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=7}] run tp @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=7}] ~ ~ ~ -68 12.5
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=8}] run tp @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=8}] ~ ~ ~ -55 11
```

(don't do that to me ever again!!!)